# How to deactivate one or more items in a list-box using primeng or angular2?

Tags: angular, listbox, primeng

I am trying to deactivate one or more items according to data. For example, I have a list of cities with disable/active field, for example, and I pushed the city names in a `SelectItem[]` array.

```
NewYork, active
Rome, disable
London, active
Istanbul, disable
Paris, active
```

[image]

```
 this.cities.push({label:'New York', value:'New York'});
 this.cities.push({label:'Rome', value:'Rome'}); // want to disable
 this.cities.push({label:'London', value:'London'});
 this.cities.push({label:'Istanbul', value:'Istanbul'}); // want to disable
 this.cities.push({label:'Paris', value:'Paris'});
```

I tried to render the list-box in using primeng example

```
<p-listbox [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"  filter="filter">
  <ng-template let-city pTemplate="item" >
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <span >{{city.value}}</span>
        </div>
  </ng-template>      
</p-listbox>
```

In primeng, list-box has one attribute called `disabled`. If I set it then it disabled the whole list-box. But I want to disable only the specific items.
Here is the implemented Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/7MHSzdmvIWNpdHsEy4F9?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker seems to be throwing some errors.

Comment: @Zze updated it. Just missing to add the module

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a mutator for `selectedCity`...

```
private _selectedCity: string;
private set selectedCity(city:string) {
    if(isactive){... do stuff ...}
}
```

However obviously this might not be great for user experience as the item would still be clickable.